# How to attach an input checkbox to a form (button_to)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

In my Rails app I have two "button_to" tags (so they are forms)

```
= button_to("Validate", validate_contracts_path , {method: :patch, class: "bulk-selection"})
= button_to("Sign", sign_contracts_path , {method: :patch, class: "bulk-selection"})
```

and I have a checkbox collection below in a table, each checkbox represents a row, they are to perform bulk actions and the checkboxes are not included in the form.

```
td = check_box_tag "selected_records[#{record.id}]"
```

I would like to know if it is possible to attach the checkboxes when one of the buttons is clicked.

The more rails way the better, but it would be great too if it is achieve with JS

Thanks

Code Details:
I don't know what else can I add to rails code. Here you are in HTML:

**Buttons**

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/contracts/sign">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
  <input class="bulk-selection" type="submit" value="Firm">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="rTxalZoJ7H4VgSsa4dlrpCe+/uXitZDRhFo6F/qIZbgIoHTh42Qb2gy9dvgDmtKqT2L1x0oYx6EzPXBNKB0KBA==">
</form>
```

**Cell in the table**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_records[1]" id="selected_records_1" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_records[2]" id="selected_records_2" value="2"></td>
...
<td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_records[10]" id="selected_records_10" value="10"></td>
```

Comment: Will you pls provide more code details?

Comment: Done! Tell me If you need something else! Thanks for your time

Comment: So, checkbox are outside the form, You need to get the all checked checkbox in jQuery and append it to form.
`chekedvalues = "";
      $('input[name="test"]:checked').each(function() {
        chekedvalues += $(this).val() + ",";
      });` and then get form object and append new field to form with this `chekedvalues`

Comment: Or you can simply add your all checkbox in form tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated snippest for your issue.
Add one class in `checkbox` called `selected_records` and add JS code to get the checked checkbox values, Also add one `hidden` field in your `form` called `selected_records` with same `id`, after fetching all checked valus set it to `selected_records` as below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".bulk-selection").click(function(){
        test = $('.selected_records:checked').map(function() {return this.value;}).get().join(',');
        $("#selected_records").val(test);
    });
});
</script>   

    <td><input type="checkbox" class="selected_records" name="selected_records[1]" id="selected_records_1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="selected_records" name="selected_records[2]" id="selected_records_2" value="2"></td>
    ...
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="selected_records" name="selected_records[10]" id="selected_records_10" value="10"></td>


<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/contracts/sign">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
    <input class="bulk-selection" type="submit" value="Firm">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="rTxalZoJ7H4VgSsa4dlrpCe+/uXitZDRhFo6F/qIZbgIoHTh42Qb2gy9dvgDmtKqT2L1x0oYx6EzPXBNKB0KBA==">
    <!-- New Hidden field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_records" id="selected_records">
</form>
```

Hope this will help you.